# error al ejecutar knitr kable con salida .pdf tras actualizar Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

He actualizado r (4.3.0) y Rstudio (RStudio 2023.03.1 Build 446) y cuando he intentado ejecutar knitr con salida .pdf (knitr to pdf) en un documento rmarkdown (.rmd) se produce un error inesperado al renderizar. Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto el código directamente en la consola se genera la tabla con normalidad:

```
processing file: apuestas.rmd
  |......................                              |  43% [rmlatitu]       
Quitting from lines 1130-1412 [rmlatitu] (apuestas.rmd)
Error in `footnote()`:
! no se pudo encontrar la función "footnote"
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% ...
                                                                                                            
Ejecución interrumpida
```

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Madrid
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] kableExtra_1.3.4 knitr_1.43       rmarkdown_2.21   scales_1.2.1    
 [5] gglorenz_0.0.2   ggrepel_0.9.3    fuzzyjoin_0.1.6  lubridate_1.9.2 
 [9] forcats_1.0.0    stringr_1.5.0    dplyr_1.1.2      purrr_1.0.1     
[13] readr_2.1.4      tidyr_1.3.0      tibble_3.2.1     tidyverse_2.0.0 
[17] ggspatial_1.1.8  gridExtra_2.3    ggExtra_0.10.0   ggplot2_3.4.2   
[21] rmapshaper_0.5.0 sf_1.0-13       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.0   viridisLite_0.4.2  farver_2.1.1      
 [4] fastmap_1.1.1      promises_1.2.0.1   digest_0.6.31     
 [7] timechange_0.2.0   mime_0.12          lifecycle_1.0.3   
[10] ellipsis_0.3.2     magrittr_2.0.3     compiler_4.3.0    
[13] sass_0.4.6         rlang_1.1.1        tools_4.3.0       
[16] utf8_1.2.3         yaml_2.3.7         labeling_0.4.2    
[19] sp_1.6-0           classInt_0.4-9     curl_5.0.0        
[22] xml2_1.3.4         KernSmooth_2.23-21 miniUI_0.1.1.1    
[25] withr_2.5.0        grid_4.3.0         fansi_1.0.4       
[28] xtable_1.8-4       e1071_1.7-13       colorspace_2.1-0  
[31] cli_3.6.1          generics_0.1.3     stringdist_0.9.10 
[34] rstudioapi_0.14    httr_1.4.6         tzdb_0.4.0        
[37] cachem_1.0.8       DBI_1.1.3          proxy_0.4-27      
[40] parallel_4.3.0     rvest_1.0.3        s2_1.1.4          
[43] vctrs_0.6.2        V8_4.3.0           webshot_0.5.4     
[46] jsonlite_1.8.4     geojsonsf_2.0.3    hms_1.1.3         
[49] systemfonts_1.0.4  ineq_0.2-13        jquerylib_0.1.4   
[52] units_0.8-2        glue_1.6.2         stringi_1.7.12    
[55] gtable_0.3.3       later_1.3.1        munsell_0.5.0     
[58] pillar_1.9.0       htmltools_0.5.5    R6_2.5.1          
[61] wk_0.7.3           evaluate_0.21      shiny_1.7.4       
[64] lattice_0.21-8     highr_0.10         bslib_0.4.2       
[67] httpuv_1.6.11      class_7.3-22       Rcpp_1.0.10       
[70] svglite_2.1.1      xfun_0.39          pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN:
Es un error conocido:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76118194/error-when-loading-kableextra-in-markdown-file-after-updating-to-r-4-3-0

Hay dos opciones:

1. Dejar el YAML del documento rmarkdown con una sóla salida (output).
2. Actualizar el package kableExtra en su versión de desarrollo `devtools::install_github("kupietz/kableExtra")`

Comment: Es un error conocido. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76118194/error-when-loading-kableextra-in-markdown-file-after-updating-to-r-4-3-0